# Wiggle (shake) effect within my app is freezing the iPhone (iOS 5)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, icons, home-button

In my iOS app I have a screen with a bunch of icons that have a wiggle effect. When I press and hold one of them they start to shake (like iphone's menu) but if I press the home button (to send my app to background) the iphone freezes! After some time, it restarts itself. This is the source I'm using to do the effect:

```
CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
[anim setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
[anim setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI/30]];
[anim setDuration:0.1];
[anim setRepeatCount:NSUIntegerMax];
[anim setAutoreverses:YES];
[self.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"SpringboardShake"];
```

And to stop:

```
[self.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

This problem only happens in iOS 5. The same code works fine in iOS 4. Any ideas about what would be making my device freezes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same problem occured with me. A solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658675/the-device-freezes-when-there-are-a-lot-of-uiview-animation-running-with-uilabel).

To have a smooth animation, you need to increase your calculations speed. So, one form is decreasing the things we need to calculate.